# how to apply Google autocomplete on bootstrap tag-Input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```js
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var tags_input = document.getElementById('tags');
        var tag_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(tags_input );
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

```html
 <div class="form-group wish-tags">
      <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Already visited:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="tags" name="visited_tags" class="form-control">
      </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible that Google autocomplete API apply on bootstrap tag input.i tried this code but its not working..please guide me

Comment: what is google address??

Comment: Google autocomplete API

Comment: Put your function call in document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

I made it in one of my website like this:

```
<input type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="tags" name="visited_tags" class="form-control">

<script>
    function initAutocomplete() {
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('tags')),
            {types: ['geocode']});
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Obviously you have to register an api key in google console